# Storing arrays generated by a recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

How can I save all the arrays generated by the following method?

```
static void permute(java.util.List<Character> arr, int k) {
    for (int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        java.util.Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
        permute(arr, k + 1);
        java.util.Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
    }
    if (k == arr.size() - 1) {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr.toArray()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `result` list of list as a parameter to your recursive method to hold the results.

```
static void permute(List<Character> arr, int k,List<List<Character>> results) {
 for (int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    java.util.Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
    permute(arr, k + 1, results);
    java.util.Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
 }
 if (k == arr.size() - 1) {
   results.add(new ArrayList<>(arr));
 }
}
```